# Routing "actions" in a httphandler (.ashx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm currently working in a webforms project, but I would like to have routing similar to the .net mvc pattern when making ajax calls to my generichandler.ashx. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
public class GenericHandler : BaseView, IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request["Action"] != null)
        {
            switch (HttpContext.Current.Request["Action"])
            {
                case "Foo":
                    Foo();
                    break;
                    //etc...
```

It works, but I think it's a pretty ugly solution. So this is where I need your help. Any suggestions on how to improve the routing is appreciated. Dynamic function names passed in with the request perhaps?

Comment: Why not integrate ASP.NET MVC? It runs in a web forms app with very little work.

Comment: ...my thoughts exactly. You're already in IIS, so why not MVC too?

Comment: @DanielA.White Ok, but this is a very old project. You're saying that it'll be "very little work" even then?

Comment: @Johan what version of .net is it targeting? if its targeting 3.5 or later, it can be done.

Comment: @DanielA.White Then I'm afraid I've got some bad news... Thanks for the tip though

Comment: @Johan what version is it targetting?

Comment: @DanielA.White According to my IIS: 2.0

Comment: 2.0 in iis can support .net 3.5 - are you using any linq?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes I am

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx